# Node.js: Differ between post data

Tags: node.js

When handling POST data, is there any way how to differ between `multipart/form-data` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: Are you using any platform?

Comment: I understood that. are you using any other libraries such as Express with it?

Comment: Nope, express does this on its own. I'm trying to write my own POST data parser.

Comment: You might be interested in [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) as an example of an existing solution that you can use. Or use as inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express then in your middleware you can find the Content-Type set in headers using

`req.headers['Content-Type']`

This will return the type of post data.